# How to dynamically generate urls used by grails.plugins.springsecurity?

Tags: grails, spring-security

This is not one of the simple questions.. So let me explain it in detail...

**The background**:
In my grails application I have this mapping:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/$storeId/$controller/$action?/$id?"
        ...
    }
}
```

This means that all url's my application will process has preceding url parameter "storeId". All controllers will use this parameter to render content and perform other actions...

Also I have controller with annotation

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
class SomeController {
    def index = {   
        // ...
    }
}
```

Let's say user is trying to access this page:

```
/555/some/index
```

If this is unauthenticated user, security-plugin will redirect him to the

```
/login/auth
```

**The issue is**:
When spring-security will redirect to this page, user will see 404. This happens because login controller will handle only urls like

```
/555/login/auth
```

**The question is**:
What should I do to dynamically build this url?

**p.s.**
It turns out that:

- There is config param for
  spring-security, called
  "auth.loginFormUrl". But this is just
  static text. And I need to build this
  url based on what url influenced this
  redirection
- The redirection is done (I'm not 100%
  sure) in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint#commence.
  But how to override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically that's a static value, but it's called from `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.getLoginFormUrl()`, so you could subclass that and do a dynamic calculation of the url in an overridden method. The plugin already subclasses it with `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AjaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint` so you should extend that.

To register your implementation instead of the plugins, add a bean override in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
import com.yourcompany.yourapp.YourAuthenticationEntryPoint
beans = {
   authenticationEntryPoint(YourAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
      loginFormUrl = '/login/auth' // has to be specified even though it's ignored
      ajaxLoginFormUrl = '/login/authAjax'
      portMapper = ref('portMapper')
      portResolver = ref('portResolver')
   }
}
```

You don't have direct access to the request in this method, but it's available in a thread-local - call `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityRequestHolder.getRequest()`.

Comment: Thank you! Actually found the same solution today. Works like a magic =) BTW: In order to override onSuccess and onFailure urls had to override RedirectStrategy.